# How do I remove Lenovo Veriface from the login screen?

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop, veriface

I have a Lenovo laptop which came preloaded with Windows 7.
Every time I start the computer and get to the Windows log-in screen (where you enter the user password) I get a message about Veriface software giving me the option to use it.
I'd like to disable this.

I went over the Program's settings and there is nothing that allows you to disable it from loading with Windows.

Also, I thought that it might be a service to disable, but I don't see it in the list of services, nor is it in the list of start-up Processes (either in msconfig or in the registry).

I'm considering uninstalling it completely, but since it's a part of the lenovo software pack that came with the computer and I do use some of these software, I'm not sure if uninstalling it might also remove wanted things (and uninstalling and reinstalling if needed seems like a mess).

Anybody know if there's an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up uninstalling Veriface.
It made the expected mess, it got rid of the problem but other Lenovo programs that came with the computer did not work.

Reinstalling one of them seems to have fixed all of them.
I guess there's a shared part that gets installed/uninstalled.

And of course, I still consider this a work-around and not a solution to the problem.
There has to be a way to simply not run the program even if it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

you have [here](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Value-line/Disabling-Veriface/td-p/5247) the tuto to disable it.

Hope this help!

Comment: The first answer-post says 'uninstall', the rest are people complaining.
As I said, uninstalling is a last resort, only if there is no way to keep it and just not run it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is a way to bypass the webcam at least. If it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Rather than deleting the program, just disable it so it can be used later when you have consistent lighting or don't mind removing your glasses for both initialization and loggin on. Go to Start - All Programs - Lenovo VeriFace Recognition #  - click on VeriFace Recognition #  - click on 3rd tab with the wrench (settings) - Unclick check mark in Logon settings - Click save on the bottom botton with the crossed hammer and wrench. .

Comment: As I said, I went over the settings, the mark is unchecked, the program still loads (it doesn't show the camera-view, it shows a black message window with buttons to start the program or 'leave a message') it shows above the password field, so I can log-on but it is a nuisance).

Comment: @Xenorose Try steps in link I posted above.

Comment: Please, avoid leaving answers that are only links. It's prefered to post all the necessary steps here. Remember: links can become broken!